# Обратное геокодирование с помощью API Яндекс.Карты

Tags: api, яндекс-карты, геокодирование

Всем привет !

Есть координаты, как по ним получить адрес?
Объясните, пожалуйста, на простом примере.

Comment: Вот прям инструкция по шагам: 
1) Открыть описание API
2) Посмотреть примеры на одном из предложенных ЯП
3) Выбрать пример и попробовать его в действии
4) вооплотить в коде понравившийся вариант

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам подойдет HTTP API Геокодера, вот примеры и документация: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/examples/geocoder_examples-docpage/

Важно: результаты должны быть отображены на общедоступной карте; результаты геокодирования нельзя сохранять и использовать без карты. Полные условия использования здесь: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/#index__conditions

К геокодеру можно обращаться также с помощью JavaScript API, вот пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/reverse_geocode