Реализация SearchControl в yandex maps JS API v3
В версии 2 yandex maps JS API есть элемент SearchControl
    // Создадим экземпляр элемента управления «поиск по карте»
    // с установленной опцией провайдера данных для поиска по организациям.
    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
        options: {
            provider: 'yandex#search'
        }
    });
    
    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);

Песочница Yandex https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo
Насколько я понял, в версии 3 его нет.
В связи с этим возникает 2 вопроса:

Какая альтернатива в версии 3?
Как долго версия 2 будет доступна и будет поддерживаться?


Geocoder  ? => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1087295/264178 => https://yandex.ru/dev/geocode/doc/ru/examples

В третьей версии API вы можете добавить на карту своё кастомное поисковое поле, например <input type="text" id="search">. И использовать поле для поиска через ymaps3.search организаций в том числе:
var textInput = document.getElementById("search");
textInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
    // Поиск адреса по Enter
        ymaps3.search({
            'text': textInput.value
        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res[0])
        })
    }
});

Версия 2.1 более не развивается, но поддерживается сервисом, и в ближайшей перспективе планов отключать её нет. До сих пор сервис не отключил даже первую версию JS API.

А можно точнее про ymaps3.search ?
Ссылка куда-то не туда

Ссылка верная, текст выделен в ней правильно. Но структура этого раздела справки ещё содержит недоработки и прокручивает к другому разделу. Попробуйте эту ссылку: https://clck.ru/3BQpMh Выделенный текст в хромиум-браузере должен указать на нужный блок.
